# Failed loading ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.1-vc14-nts.dll and Error:No code coverage driver is available

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, xdebug

so i've been doing some unit testing on my laravel project. I need to know the code coverage of my test and so do i install xdebug on my computer. but after i follow the installation guide i always get this error

> PS D:\Telkom\tpncms> vendor\bin\phpunit tests\Feature\WebmasterBannersTest.php
>
> Failed loading ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.1-vc14-nts.dll
>
> PHPUnit 6.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Error:         No code coverage driver is available
>
> ..........                                                        10 / 10 (100%)
>
> Time: 3.79 seconds, Memory: 26.00MB

here are the snippet of my php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.1-vc14-nts.dll
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log="c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
; 3600 (1 hour), 36000 = 10h
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

i also pass my php info to download the Xdebug version from the https://xdebug.org/wizard.php recommendation, so i get the right installation for my device. ive been searching for the right solution from this site like changing the php.ini, or changing the Xdebug version, but nothings work

while in the php info the xdebug is appearing. where does it go wrong?
im using laravel 5.5 and visual studio code as my text editor

i installed my xdebug on C:\PHP7.1\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.1-vc14-nts.dll.

is it because i already installed the php outside the php that come with the XAMPP?
if so how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

the problem has been asnwered, the problem is my server is using the php ini that located in xampp, while my xdebugs installed in my php folder outside the xampp. so i change the local environment for the php into the xampp folder